# Parse tree building with ANTLR and Java

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, antlr, antlr4

Hello I need some help regarding building a simple parse tree with antlr and java .
I have tried to work with powershell to compile and run the grammar file ( which is the pascal.g4 file ) and I was hoping to generate some java files out of it , however at times when I tried to run it using the command  " .\antlr.bat -package pdl -o pdl .\pascal.g4 "  I get a message on the powershell 
stating  " The system cannot find the file specified " .

I think the command I typed in might be wrong but anyway I have got the grammar file and I have got the  .bat files ( grun.bat , java.bat  &  javac.bat  )  and the   antlr-4.5-complete.jar file .

I think these are basically all the files you need to build the parse tree .
As for the folder location where all these files are located is  C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\test2 
I have looked at some examples from others however I really now cannot go any further , can anybody please help me out here to build this .

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK, the standard ANTLR distribution does not include an 'antlr.bat' file.  In any case, the problem resolution depends on the contents of that file. Post it.

Comment: I understand it does not include  antlr.bat  file , that is why I had to download it from the  antlr website .

Answer (score 1):

That batch file is little more than a hint.

Try being explicit with the paths and arguments -- and without trying to coerce Powershell into passing arguments in a manner compatible with batchfile execution.

Something like this:

```
@echo off
rem Execute the Antlr compiler/generator tool

SETLOCAL
set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\test2\antlr-4.5-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

cd /d C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\test2\
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe" org.antlr.v4.Tool pascal.g4

timeout 4
```

Comment: Right now I have just edited the location in the  antlr.bat  file , 
I have put the location as you showed me in your example , so now the
.bat file contents are these  :




 set basedir="C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\test2\antlr-4.5-complete.jar;"

  set cp=%basedir%\jre\lib\rt.jar

%basedir%\bin\java.exe -cp %cp%;.;antlr-4.5-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool %*

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one-liner version I use, adopted from ***The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference*** to use a relative reference to the directory containing the .CMD/.BAT file...

`@java -cp %~dp0..\ClassLib\antlr-4.5-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH% org.antlr.v4.Tool %*`

Use of `%~dp0` helps avoid hardcoding an absolute path in it...